# Does .NET 5 support the old csproj format?

Tags: .net, .net-5, csproj, .net-framework-version

One of the biggest hurdles when migrating from .NET Framework to .NET 5+ is having to convert all csproj's to the new SDK-style format. There is no tool to automate this, it has to be done manually.

I wonder if this conversion is necessary? Is there a way to switch to .NET while keeping the old cs projects?

With 300+ projects in my team's solution it looks like we are never going to switch. It's just too much work.

I have tried updating the <TargetFramework> manually and that didn't work.

Maybe I'm missing something and there is a way to achieve this?

Comment: I have seen this project https://github.com/hvanbakel/CsprojToVs2017 and Scott Hanselman made a migration tool before that might still work: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/upgrading-an-existing-net-project-files-to-the-lean-new-csproj-format-from-net-core
Those can be useful if you are not targeting the latest .NET version.

Comment: Microsoft provided tools to help with the upgrade away from .NET Framework that would handle moving to the SDK style .csproj - https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/upgrade-assistant

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer to you question but it may help.  My goal wasn't to convert to .net 5, just to convert my projects to SDK style.

I have a solution of four.net 4.0 projects including a WPF project and also four xUnit test projects.  There is a .net [upgrade assistant](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/upgrade-assistant) I used and I just stopped after the "convert project to sdk style step". It worked mostly without issues. I got the idea from this [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63055430/how-to-create-an-sdk-style-net-framework-project-in-vs/75316293#75316293) (see comment under accepted answer).

The link above says Visual Studio 2022 or latter but I have 2019 and it worked fine.  I think it says that as you'll need 2022 if you are doing the full migration to .net 6/7.

The only other thing I did before converting to SDK was update each project to use PackageReference instead of packages.config. I'm not sure if that's important as I did this before deciding to convert my projects to SDK-style. If you right click on the project you'll see a command called "migrate package.config to package reference".  After doing that for all projects then go to Tools > Nuget Package Manager > Package Manager Settings and under Package Manager set the "Default package management format" to PackageReference. See [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference/).

I then converted each project one at a time ensuring each one built OK before moving on to the next project.  The only issue I ran into is the migration assistant adds a more recent version of Microsoft.CSharp to each project reference. For my WPF project I had to remove that and replace with the version for .net 4.0; for the other projects I just had to remove it as it wasn't being used.  I'm not sure why it does that but thinking it's for a subsequent step in the migration.

The csprojs are now much cleaner.  Also enables the "Remove unused references" option in the project right-click menu.

I also confirmed I'm able to use dotnet build myProject.csproj from the command line as well.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **No, it does not.**

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/#considerations-when-porting

> [..] the project files for .NET use a different format than .NET Framework, known as the SDK-style project format.